# post-hoc probing with a categorical IV

Tags: regression, categorical-data, linear, post-hoc

I have a significant interaction between a categorical IV (2 conditions) and a continuous moderator in predicting a continuous DV. I would like to posthoc probe these findings; however, I've never post-hoc probed findings with a categorical IV so I'm not 100% sure what to do. Consistent with the Holmbeck (2002) and Aiken & West (1991) approaches for post-hoc probing, I plan to create the following variables.

highmod = mod-SD of moderator.
lowmod = mod+SD of moderator.

highmodxcondition1 = highmod x condition 1.
lowmodxcondition1 = lowmod x condition 1.

highmodxcondition2 = highmod x condition 2.
lowmodxcondition2 = lowmod x condition 2.

I have 2 questions. 1. Can someone confirm that the variables that I created for post-hoc probing look correct? 2. Does anyone have a link to a plot where I can plot these values?

Thanks,
D